# Chaning text of href from script makes text vanish and not change

Tags: javascript, html

This is function is called when clicking a button in my page:

```
function LoadEnglishText()
{
    document.getElementById("txt_whatwedo_learnmore2").innerHTML = "here."; 
}
```

This is the corresponding HTML:

```
<a id="txt_whatwedo_learnmore2" href="./pdf/Pricing_App_Dev_2019_Ger.pdf">hier.</a>
```

So, upon firing the function, the text of the link should change from "hier." to "here." (from German to English), but it doesn't. When clicked on, it simply vanishes off screen.

What is it I am doing wrong?

EDIT:

The function is called like so:

```
        <a href="#" onclick="LoadEnglishText()"> <img src="./img/img_english.png" width=3%</img></a>
```

This all works on every other text but not on the link...

**********EDIT 2************
I have just realised that firefox console says that `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`

allthough the ID is correct. This is the only instance where I am tring to change a LINK in the function. It is usually just a text element so it must be connected to this...

Comment: Where are you calling the function ? Add the related code to help

Comment: it works. Where is the click binding? If it's *on* the `a` tag you're going to need to prevent the default action of following the link

Comment: Please include the button in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason could be that your button is of type submit, when clicking that the from is submitted and the page disappears. You can either prevent the default event using [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) or specify the button type as `button`.

**Please Note:** It is better to use `textContent` or `innerText` when the content is plain text.

```js
function LoadEnglishText(e){
  document.getElementById("txt_whatwedo_learnmore2").textContent = "here."; 
}
```

```html
<a id="txt_whatwedo_learnmore2" href="./pdf/Pricing_App_Dev_2019_Ger.pdf">hier.</a>

<button type="button" onclick="LoadEnglishText()">Change Text</button>
```

Using [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```js
function LoadEnglishText(e){
  document.getElementById("txt_whatwedo_learnmore2").textContent = "here."; 
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<a id="txt_whatwedo_learnmore2" href="./pdf/Pricing_App_Dev_2019_Ger.pdf">hier.</a>

<button onclick="LoadEnglishText(event)">Change Text</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to prevent the reload of the link with [`event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

like :

```
function LoadEnglishText(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("txt_whatwedo_learnmore2").innerText = "here."; 
}
```

---

```
<a href="#" onclick="LoadEnglishText(event)"> <img src="./img/img_english.png"></img></a>
```

**Note:** use `.innerText` if you push text only.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call function using parenthesis() `onclick="LoadEnglishText()"`.

A working demo:

```js
function LoadEnglishText(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("txt_whatwedo_learnmore2").innerHTML = "here.";
}
```

```html
<a id="txt_whatwedo_learnmore2" onclick="LoadEnglishText(event)">hier.</a>
```